# Can not get alert in service of angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="canerApp" ng-controller="canerCtrl">

    <button ng-click="click()">
      Button click
    </button>

    <p ng-show="isClicked">

      name=
      <input type="text" ng-model="caner.name">
      <br> surnanme=
      <input type="text" ng-model="caner.surname">
      <br> age

        <select ng-model="caner.age"

       ng-options="  person.age as person.age for person in peole" >
        </select>

      <br> Welcome Message: {{ caner.name + " " + caner.surname+" "+caner.age}}
    </p>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('canerApp', []);

    app.controller('canerCtrl', function($scope,$window) {
$window.alert("ctrl");
      $scope.caner = {

        name: "caner",
        surname: "aydin",

age: "22",
      };

      $scope.peole = [{
        age: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
      }, {
        age: 2,
        name: 'Alice'
      }, {
        age: 3,
        name: 'Steve'
      }];

      $scope.isClicked = true;

      $scope.click = function(User) {
        $window.alert("ctrl fun");
        $scope.isClicked = !$scope.isClicked;
        $scope.caner.name = User.save;
      };
    });

    app 
.factory('User', function($http,$window) { // injectables go here
  var backendUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
  $window.alert("service");
  var service = {
    // our factory definition
    user: {},
    setName: function(newName) { 
      service.user['name'] = newName; 
    },
    setEmail: function(newEmail) {
      service.user['email'] = newEmail;
    },
    save: function() {  $window.alert("service saave");
      return $http.post(backendUrl + '/users', {
        user: service.user
      });
    }
  };
  return service;
});

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

this is my code. it can be seen here

http://plnkr.co/edit/gP2NcC38JPsabQFacGkb?p=preview

i merged lots of codes. so there are some unnecessary codes.

What i want is when i click, i can see alert of

```
ctrl fun
```

and at firsst start, the alert of `ctrl`

but cant see the alerts in service.

controller should call service but it doesnot call.

the call is here in conroller

```
  $scope.caner.name = User.save;
```

i tried also

User.save

or `$scope.var = User.save`

or

```
  $scope.click = function(User,$scope) {
        $window.alert("ctrl fun");
        $scope.isClicked = !$scope.isClicked;
        $scope.caner.name = User.save;
      };
    });
```

but this made worse because it did not even give alert of ctrl.

because probably he was using scope of controller.

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject the User factory into your controller otherwise it will not get instantiated:

```
app.controller('canerCtrl', function($scope,$window,User) {...}
```

Regarding your service-call, make sure you do not define another User variable in your click-function. $scope and User are already available in the controller.

```
$scope.click = function() {
    $scope.whatever = User.save();
}
```

However, keep in mind that you return a promise from your save-function, not a name.

Comment: save: function() {  $window.alert("service saave"); but cant geet alert from here

Comment: Did you remember to inject `$window` into your controller?

Comment: no i ut like that save: function($window
) {  $window.alert("service saave");
      return $http.post(backendUrl + '/users', {
        user: service.user
      });
    }
  };

Comment: Then you should use the debugger of your browser and set a breakpoint in your save-function and check, if it is called and then if `$window` is defined. If you are not feeling comfortable with the debugger, you can use console logging to check the function call and $window. Use `console.log('window: ', typeof $window)`.

Comment: i put  save: function() {  $window.alert("service saave");console.log('winfdow: ', typeof $window)
      return $http.post(backendUrl + '/users', {
        user: service.user
      }); but it did not come in console bbut when i put app 
.factory('User', function($http,$window) { // injectables go here
  $window.alert("service");
  console.log('windowff: ', typeof $window) it came

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr where I can reproduce that behaviour?

Comment: here it is sir http://plnkr.co/edit/gP2NcC38JPsabQFacGkb?p=preview it goes service then controller but when i  click, it doesnot give even cnsole. http://plnkr.co/edit/oPNljOI3eyZmICKJqcd8?p=preview but here it gives alert when ckicked

Comment: Well in both cases I see alerts. You won't see a console log on click, as you print to console during instantiation of your controller. That happens once in the beginning, not on every click.

Comment: but i dont get alert or log i wanted. do you see this alert save: function() { // $window.alert("service saave");
     console.log('window: ', "service save");

Comment: Well you need to actually call your functions. Like `User.save()` so far, you are only assigning them.